# PHP - Overloaded object of type SimpleXMLElement is not compatible with ArrayObject

Tags: php, simplexml

I would like to be able to use `SimpleXMLElement` Object as an Associative array.
I am trying to convert it using the `ArrayObject` class.

What is so special in a `SimpleXMLElement` Object that it is **not compatible** with `ArrayObject` class?

**Note**: I am able to convert it in other ways but I am curious why this method does not work.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
...
var_dump(new ArrayObject(simplexml_import_dom($dom)));
```

Gives me: **Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Overloaded object of type SimpleXMLElement is not compatible with ArrayObject'**

Comment: I'm not clear what you're trying to achieve. SimpleXML **already** behaves like an array, with the string keys representing attributes of the current node. What is the actual problem you're trying to solve where you think `ArrayObject` would be nicer to work with than `SimpleXMLElement` itself?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are casting it wrong

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML("<html><body>Hello</body></html>");

$myArray = (Array)simplexml_import_dom($dom);

echo $myArray["body"]; //prints "hello"
```

**Explanation**
ArrayObject suppose to get an object and convert it to a array.

> What makes SimpleXMLElement tricky to work with is that it feels and behaves like an object, but is actually a system RESOURCE,  (specifically a libxml resource).

**Edit**
 cast the entire xml to array:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML("<html><body><div><span>Hello</span></div></body></html>");

$myArray = json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_import_dom($dom)),true);

print_r($myArray);
```

**result:**

```
Array
(
    [body] => Array
        (
            [div] => Array
                (
                    [span] => Hello
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: The problem with the code you provided is that casting affects only the first dimension of the object. If you have a multidimensional object which contains other objects - they are not being casted.

Comment: you are right. sorry for that, I added an edit. @Boarking

Comment: Note that the `json_decode(json_encode())` trick is a **lossy conversion** - it will discard anything that can't neatly be encoded in a plain array, but which was easily accessible in the original SimpleXMLElement object. You're normally better off deciding what information you want out and creating the array "by hand" using [basic SimpleXML operations](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php).